# React how to append new element to state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'd like to append new element to my products state, currently using `.concat` but it's adding to the end of an array, but I need to add to the beginning.

```
var Body = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { products: [] }
  },

  handleSubmit(product) {
    var newState = this.state.products.concat(product);

    this.setState({ products: newState });
  },
});
```

Tried to used `this.state.products.unshift(product)` but it's giving me `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.tickets.unshift is not a function` that's probably it returns length of an array not itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the order of your concatenation.  If "product" is a single item and not an array, then do this:

```
var newState = [product].concat(this.state.products);
```

if "product" is already an array, just this:

```
var newState = product.concat(this.state.products);
```